# Searching file stores accross WAN link

Tags: search, crawling

I have a Sharepoint 2010 farm at my main office that is crawling all of our file stores.  It works great to the local sites, but we have remote offices with file servers as well.  One site also has a smaller WAN connection, so may take multiple days for an incremental crawl.  Is there a way to add a server to the farm and have it do the crawl of the file store locally?

We are running Sharepoint 2010 Standard, not Enterprise.

Comment: Can you give us an update on that topic, please?

Answer (score 1):

Geographical distribution of one farm is not supported, so you can not "extend" your existing farm with a new server at another location. Hwowever, you can set up a new farm for the remote office locally or you can try to improve your WAN performance via WAN-Accelerators.

Maybe someone has a smart idea about integrating the farms and its search results? You might want to try federated search.